# Understanding nginx prerender.io configuration

Tags: nginx, prerender

I recently read the nginx + prerender.io tutorial:

https://gist.github.com/thoop/8165802

And i've been trying to understand it. I know that it passes through prerender.io service but it think it should be something like

```
proxy_pass http://$prerender/$scheme://$host$request_uri?;
```

instead

```
if ($prerender = 1) {

    #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
    set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
    rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
    proxy_pass http://$prerender;
}
```

Or maybe the rewrite sentence do it for me. I just want to understand it. Thanks.

Comment: You are correct, those two statements are doing the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, it's now a little bit more clear now.